# Reposition the Activity Indicator inside UIAlertView

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm using a UIAlertView with an Activity indicator inside of it, but the indicator is not positioned correctly. I'm sure that i'm missing something very small, but it would be great if any one can help me. Below are my code and corresponding code snippet

```
var progressAlert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Downloading", message: "Patients information...", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: nil);


    var loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    loadingIndicator.center = CGPointMake(progressAlert.bounds.size.width/2, progressAlert.bounds.size.height - 150)
    loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
    loadingIndicator.startAnimating()

    progressAlert.setValue(loadingIndicator, forKey: "accessoryView")
    progressAlert.show()
```

[image]

**Edit:** Following Matt's answer, ended up creating custom view and it works like a charm.

Comment: it is coming at centre for me. Can you specify where it is not positioned properly?

Comment: i'm trying to move the Activity indicator few pixels up, as you can see it is sticking to the bottom of the alert view. you know how to do that?

Comment: oh. Now I get what you are saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here. One is that you are making an assumption about the ultimate size of the `progressAlert` - you are positioning the activity indicator based on what the `progressAlert` frame is *now*, rather than based on what it *will be* when it appears. You can probably solve that by using constraints instead of an absolute `center` value.

However, the bigger problem is that what you are doing is illegal. Do not add your own subviews to a UIAlertView. Instead, make your own view controller with your own view and present it. It can *look* like an alert (i.e. be small, centered, dim out the rest of the interface) but now it is your view and you can do anything you like in it.

Comment: Ok, so basically you are saying that i need to create a custom view and we cannot modify the UIAlertView. That was my plan b and i guess i'l go ahead and work on that. Thanks matt

Comment: It's a lot easier than you might think. Feel free to steal the code from my github example!

Comment: Yea, i've already used something similar in my code. I just thought it would be easier and lot of less code to have UIAlertView doing all that. Anyways, i've created my custom view with the activity indicator and it works like a charm. Thanks matt for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class YourFunction{
//#MARK: - showAlertView With Activity indicator
class func showAlertViewWithIndicator(TitleMessage: String, timeInterval: Double,view: UIViewController){
    let alert = UIAlertView()
    alert.delegate = self
    alert.title = TitleMessage
    let loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(50, 10, 37, 37)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
    loadingIndicator.center = view.view.center
    loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
    loadingIndicator.startAnimating();

    alert.setValue(loadingIndicator, forKey: "accessoryView")
    loadingIndicator.startAnimating()

    alert.show()

    let delay = timeInterval * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        alert.dismissWithClickedButtonIndex(-1, animated: true)

    loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
    loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    view.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    })

}
}
```

I wrote global functions for you. This will show UIAlertView with title and activity indicator. You can set the time based on TimeInterval variable. You can call it anywhere in your viewcontroller. Just type YourFunction.showAlertViewWithIndicator("Hello World",timeInterval:3.0,self)

It is for swift 2x
Just wanna help :)